# Do any temple deities wear unusual attires and is there a sthalapurana behind that?

Tags: temple, idols

For example, I recall the religious/political speaker Rangaraj Pande say that the Vishnu
idol at Srivilliputtur wears pants.

Are there other idols which are dressed unusually either seasonally or normally?